# JS - Changing HREF after interval

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make javascript that will change href after some interval. I made something but it´s not working...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
setInterval(fetch_quote,5000);
});
function fetch_quotes() {
var x = document.getElementById("Buttonn");
if document.getElementById("Buttonn").href="#primary";{
document.getElementById("Buttonn").href="#volby";
} else {
document.getElementById("Buttonn").href="#primary";
}
}
</script>
```

I am just starting with JS so i dont have some big knowledge...

Comment: `if document` is a syntax error.

Comment: Thats mistake i made writing it here in code its okay

Comment: If you want real answers, post real code. See also [mcve].

Comment: `fetch_quote` is not the same as `fetch_quotes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(fetch_quotes, 1000);
});


function fetch_quotes() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Buttonn");
  
  // if href containces '#primary'
  if (x.href.includes('#primary')) {
    // set to '/#volby'
    x.href = '/#volby';
  } else {
    // set to '/#primary'
    x.href = '/#primary';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="Buttonn" href="/#primary">
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: My code works, you can run it. It looks like you did not correctly install jquery

Comment: It works now, thank you! But when i load my page i get some pop-up message and it disappear after a half second or so. Is there a way to block that pop-up?